# Replace multiple groups of characters in an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to replace several different groups of characters in one NSString.  Currently I am doing it with several repeating methods, however I am hoping there is a way of doing this in one method:

```
NSString *result = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;B&" withString:@" "];
NSString *result2 = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;/B&gt;" withString:@" "];

NSString *result3 = [result2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"gt;" withString:@" "];
return [result3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" Description  " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in the SDK, but you could at least use a category for this so you can write something like this:

```
NSDictionary *replacements = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @" ", @"&lt;B&",
                                @" ", @"&lt;/B&gt;",
                                @" ", @"gt;"
                                @"" , @" Description  ",
                              nil];
return [html stringByReplacingStringsFromDictionary:replacements];
```

... by using something like the following:

```
@interface NSString (ReplaceExtensions)
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingStringsFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
@end

@implementation NSString (ReplaceExtensions)
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingStringsFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSMutableString *string = [self mutableCopy];
    for (NSString *target in dict) {
       [string replaceOccurrencesOfString:target withString:[dict objectForKey:target] 
               options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    }
    return [string autorelease];
}
@end
```

In modern Objective C with ARC:

```
-(NSString*)stringByReplacingStringsFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    NSMutableString *string = self.mutableCopy;
    for(NSString *key in dict)
        [string replaceOccurrencesOfString:key withString:dict[key] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    return string.copy;
}
```