# How to convert txt files containing chords and lyrics to the ChordPro format using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, converters

I am trying to convert `txt` files that contain lyrics and chords to **ChordPro** format and vice versa. So something like that:

```
G                   Em
I heard there was a secret chord

G                        Em
that David played and it pleased the Lord
```

would become:

```
[G]I heard there was [Em] a secret chord

[G] that David played and [Em] it pleased the Lord
```

I am currently using an `NSDictionary` of key values (for example key E value [E]) and use this as the basis to convert the string from the file. I am using a self defined method `stringByReplacingStringsFromDictionary` from [Replace multiple groups of characters in an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733980/replace-multiple-groups-of-characters-in-an-nsstring).

I now need to do that only when I am converting a line that actually contains chords (and no lyrics). For example I wouldn't want to convert `David` to `[D]avid`.

I thought that the best way to do this is by checking wether the line contains anything that is not identified as a chord and if so skip it. But how can I test an `NSString` against an `NSDictionary` (or other collection) in this manner?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Singletons are OK in certain circumstances, and an NSDictionary can be used to store just about anything.  Whether it's the "best" way or not is dependent on context (and you've given us virtually nothing on that).

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for checking the question :) I am not sure what more to provide. I am not concerned with the question of wether I should use a singleton or not so maybe I should avoid mentioning it in the question. I am interested in finding a flexible and efficient way for conversion. What more information would be relevant?

Comment: So your question is about the mapping of G => [G]? Well, anything will do here, NSDictionary as well as every manual mapping...

Comment: @Eiko Ok, my question is obviously too general. I thought there might be something like "you need to use this or that approach" or "Using an NSDictionary is not a good idea since..." type of answer. I am going to edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's words separated by white space and if any line contains either no words or a word that isn't recognised as a chord then it's left alone but otherwise you wrap them in square brackets and insert them at their original position into the line below?

You're going to be searching by word so I'd put the known chords into an `NSSet`. I'd then look at `NSString`'s `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`. I'd use the `newlineCharacterSet` to divide lines without having to become obsessed about carriage returns versus line feeds. I'd use the `whitespaceCharacterSet` to get a list of words on each line. Check them against the set and the decision logic is done.

You can then use sequential calls to `rangeOfString:options:range:`, modifying the third parameter as you go, to recover the character positions of chords before you threw away all the whitespace.

If it's unlikely you'll ever compile a complete list of chords then a smart way to proceed might be to mark as a chord line any line where you recognise more than, say, 50% of the words as chords or any that is reduced in length by a sufficient proportion when you remove the whitespace.

Comment: I am trying your solution but I am having trouble comparing the set with the set of chord names as the componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet is filling up the arrays but keeps the separators. The results are lots of empty strings and Strings contaning /n characters which cause the isSubsetOfSet method to return NO. Any ideas?

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:...` shouldn't keep the separators. There's nothing odd going on like interpreting UTF-16 as UTF-8 is there?

Comment: I am using this actually: `NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: _songURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];`...

Comment: Very peculiar. Is there an example file that you can put somewhere for us to sniff around?

Comment: Do you mean my code or the file I am trying to parse?

Comment: The file you're trying to parse. I can't immediately think of a reason why `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` would keep the characters in the set so it'd be interesting to have a poke around. That said, if it's commercial music then I appreciate you may not be able to post.

Comment: Here it is: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3421860/halelujiah.txt . Thank you for taking the time to have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have an NSDictionary for that.
You can just create the strings using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", chord]` where `chord` is your NSString variable containing the chord name.

Having said that, in this case, the dictionary is small and it doesn't do any harm, it's just that it is useless to fill the dictionary with data that we can deduce from one simple operation (add brackets around a string).

Comment: That is true if I am dealing with only one **known** string but I want to be able to parse the file automatically.

Comment: It is still the same thing.
If you know that there's one line with chords followed by one line of lyrics, you can deduce the value of the `chord` variable automatically while parsing. (e.g. chord will have value G and then Em..)

Detecting the chord can (and should) be done without having to store all of the possible chords in a data structure.

Comment: Reading tokou's comment, I think I'm unclear on this — is it always chord, text, empty line, chord, text, empty line?

Comment: @tokou Ah thanks :) of course you are right. Silly me. Any idea of how to identify the strings that contain chords in contrast to the ones containing lyrics?

Comment: @Tommy No this can vary. It could be that there are two consecutive lines of chords (an intro or bridge to the song) or consecutive lines of lyrics without chords.

Comment: Then I'll be honest and say I'm unclear how tokou's answer relates to your question of distinguishing chord lines from non-chord lines, but I'm glad you consider the problem solved.

Comment: @Tommy I have changed the question a few times. At the start it was if using the NSDictionary is the right approach. After your answer I am unsure wether tokou's approach will work for what I am trying to do. Maybe having a collection of known words is essential.. I will have to try it and decide on the correct answer later. Thank you both for your help :)

Comment: @Tommy What I wanted to stress is that, recognizing chords can be done without a table since, first, there's too many chords to get a complete list of them and second, differences between lines with and without chords are so strong that it is easy to recognize them. For example, if a line has only a few words (typically 1 or 2, let's say less than 4), that these words are separated with lots of spaces, that all of these words start with a capital letter and that they are composed of less than 4 characters than we can safely assume that this is a chords line and treat all the words as chords.